# Sobolev/Lebesgue norm estimates in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, integral-inequality

I'm currently working on a project in which I have to establish some estimates for some global Sobolev and Lebesgue norms.

We know that if we have a bounded domain $\Omega$, then for any $q \leq p^*$ there is a $C > 0$ such that:

$$\|u\|_{L^q} \leq C\|\nabla{u}\|_{L^p}\tag{1}$$

for any $u$.

If the domain is not bounded, we have this estimate only for $q=p^*$ (due to Gagliardo-Niremberg Inequality), because we cannot use Holder inequality to bound $L^q$ norms by other such norms with bigger $q$.

However, if we replace $\|\nabla{u}\|_{L^p}$ by $\|u\|_{W^{1,p}}$, the $\|u\|_{L^p}$ appearing on the RHS allows us to establish:

$$\|u\|_{L^q} \leq C(q)\|u\|_{W^{1,p}} \tag{2}$$

for all $p \leq q \leq p^*$.

My question is: do we have such an estimate for unbounded domains, but also for $q < p$? More generally, for which values of $q$ can we establish estimates of the form (1) and (2), when the domain is unbounded? (I'm basically interested in the case $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^3$.)

Comment: Your first inequality is already false without some restriction that you haven't specified: consider $u \equiv 1$. The most common modification of what you wrote that actually does work is for when $u \in W^{1,p}_0$.

Comment: Anyway, for your question about $q<p$, try this. Fix $p,q$, where $q<p$. Let $r>0$ and consider a smooth function which is equal to $|x|^{-r}$ off the ball of radius $1$ centered at $0$ and is nicely smooth in the ball. Tweak $r$ to make $f$ be $L^p$ but not $L^q$. (This is not hard: for instance, in the 1D case, this function is in $L^s$ if and only if $s > 1/r$.) See if this function is in $W^{1,p}$ or not. If it is then your question probably works; if it isn't then you've just proven that your question doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit hurry and thus I forgot this. It is true for the closure of compactly supported smooth functions under the seminorm of the RHS.

Comment: Is that built into the assumptions of what you want to do in the second part? Please clearly specify your assumptions, and (if applicable) where you are open to having assumptions introduced by the answerer.

Comment: I'm actually interested only in the second part. When we use the full Sobolev norm we do not need any restrictions on $u$ (we can prove the estimates for bounded domains by using extension theorem and then take limits, being always aware of constants which may explode) The first was just a quick attempt to explain something different I had in mind.

Comment: Well, do what I suggested and discuss what happens (maybe in your question). I don't actually know the answer to what I suggested, I just know that that tailing is the simplest thing that could break your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

One word: *scaling*.

Consider $u_\lambda(x) = u(\lambda x)$ where $\lambda>0$. The Lebesgue norm scales as
$$\|u_\lambda\|_p = \lambda^{-n/p}\|u\|_p$$
while the norm of the gradient scales as
$$\|\nabla u_\lambda\|_p = \lambda^{1-n/p}\|\nabla u\|_p$$
This immediately shows that $\|\nabla u_\lambda\|_p$ can control $\|u\|_q$ only when $\frac{n}{q} = 1-\frac{n}{p}$, which corresponds to $q=p^*$, the critical exponent.

The full  norm of $W^{1,p}$ has a term that scales as $\lambda^{-n/p}$ and another that scales as $\lambda^{1-n/p}$. The sum of such things  dominates the powers of $\lambda$ that are between $-n/p$ and $1-n/p$, and none others. This leads to the necessary condition
$$-\frac{n}{p}\le -\frac{n}{q} \le 1-\frac{n}{p} $$
that is, $p\le q\le p^* $.